# How to get rid of remote origin/HEAD pointing to origin/master?

Tags: git

Recently I've changed my origin remotes on two different replicated servers.

Now I have this situation one on server everything is ok:

```
$git branch -a
 * master
 remotes/origin/master
```

On the other server I have this

```
$git branch -a
 * master
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
 remotes/origin/master
```

Nothing serious since everything should work but, for cleaning sake, I'd like to have the identical situation.

So I tried:

```
git branch -d -r origin/HEAD
```

Answer is:

```
Deleted remote branch origin/HEAD (was 542d392).
```

But then I have :

```
$git branch -a
 * master
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

I also tried to prune :

```
$git pull -p  origin master
```

But still the same... no chance yet to have it clean like the other srvr.

Any hint?

Many thanks

**EDIT**

Answering comment "what happened after git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD"

```
    koala@server:~/www$ git branch -a
    * master
      remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
      remotes/origin/master
    koala@server:~/www$ git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
    koala@server:~/www$ git branch -a
    * master
      remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
    koala@server:~/www$ git branch -r
      origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Answer (score 17):

The `->` in the `git branch` output indicates that this is a symbolic reference: that is, the reference itself points not to a commit, but rather to another reference.  (That other reference can also be symbolic, but at least ideally, following all these names eventually leads to a regular reference—a non-symbolic branch name—which points to the final commit.)

The problem here is that `git branch` does not know how to delete a symbolic reference.  When you ask it to delete the remote-tracking branch `origin/HEAD`, it follows the symbolic reference, discovering that it's an alternate name for `origin/master`, and deletes `origin/master` instead.

The `git remote` command does, in later versions of Git at least, know how to remove this:

```
git remote set-head <name> --delete
```

which in this case would translate to `git remote set-head origin -d` (shortening `--delete`; see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html)).

If your Git is not new enough to support this, you can use the "plumbing" command [`git symbolic-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-symbolic-ref.html), which easily deletes symbolic references, except that you must spell them out in full:

```
git symbolic-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

If your Git version is old enough to lack the `-d` flag here, you will have to remove the symbolic reference manually, by editing `.git/packed-refs` if needed (it may not be needed and if your Git is *really* old it may never be created) and removing the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` (which is either a plain-text file containing `ref:` and the name of the other branch, or is a symbolic link if your Git is *really* old).

The name may come back anyway on `git fetch` (I had this happen to me in some Git 1.6.* or 1.7.* versions, if I remember the version numbers correctly, after I deleted the ref manually).  Different versions of Git exhibit different behaviors here.

Comment: my git version is 1.7 Tried: git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD Didn't work

Comment: What *did* happen with `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`? If you run `git branch -r` immediately afterward the symbolic reference should be gone. If you run `git fetch` or `git remote update` after that, it may, as I noted, come back. If it keeps coming back, there is basically nothing you can do other than upgrade your Git version.

Comment: koala@server:~/www$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
koala@server:~/www$ git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
koala@server:~/www$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
koala@server:~/www$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master

Comment: Since no formatting in comments: @torek I Edited my question to have my above comment displayed formatted. But basically your latest suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Aha, you'll need `git symbolic-ref -d` rather than `git update-ref -d`.  I'll fix the answer too since `git symbolic-ref -d` is the plumbing command that should work here.

Comment: Looks like in version 1.7 there's no option -d or --delete (iI alaso don't find DOC about this for git version 1.7): git symbolic-ref --delete  refs/remotes/origin/HEAD                                       
error: unknown option `delete'
usage: git symbolic-ref [options] name [ref]

    -q, --quiet           be quiet
    -m <reason>           reason of the update

Comment: Wow, that's pretty bad.  As a last resort, you can remove the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` if it exists, and edit out the line containint `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` (if that line exists) from `.git/packed-refs` (if that file exists). This is what the delete option does in newer Git versions.

Comment: looking at documentation , there's not a link to 1.7.x version about this , but If you tweak the url you can actually get to thispage: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref/1.7.1 where actually it doesn't mention anything about removing or deleting actions on symlinks.

Answer (score 4):

With GIT version:

```
C:\working-directory>git version
git version 2.13.0.windows.1

C:\working-directory>git branch --list -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

It means that in the folder:

```
C:\working-directory\.git\refs\remotes\origin
```

there is a file named **HEAD** containing just one line:

```
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

representing the "sympolic link" to the remote origin/master branch. By deleting this file we obtain the desired result:

```
C:\working-directory>git branch --list -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at :

```
git remote prune <branch>
```

It basically remove local commited branches. I' m not 100% sure it's your case, but it's worth looking closer.

EDIT:

In fact, this might be better: removes all local branches that dont exist anymore

```
git remote prune origin
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the .git folder on at root level and set the origin manually again ?

Comment: removing .git folder seems too drastic. Expecially coz i'm on production server. I tried instead to remove .git/config file. And recreate remotes. That will not work